# jQuery Mobile: UI-Panel content disappears on second time on Android 4.4.2

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

The bug occurs exclusively on Android 4.4.2. It was tested on 4.4.4 and 4.1.2, neither of them had the problem.

All content of the ui-panel disappears on close.

```
<!--menu panel-->
<div data-role="panel" id="menuPanel" data-swipe-close="true">

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input type="search" name="searchField" id="searchField" value=""/>
    </div>

    <ul id="menu" data-role="listview">

    </ul>
</div>
```

The content is dynamically generated, but that's not a problem. It closes, and none of the elements appear - even though they are clickable - THEY ARE THERE. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `z-index`. After setting `z-index` to `inherit` on all elements including the `.ui-panel` class, and putting all internal HTML text content into `span` with `style="z-index: inherit"`, the problem went away.